# XSLT transform Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have the following class:

```
public class HelloWorldDictionary
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And an XSLT like so:

```
<xsl:template match="/HelloWorldDictionary">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <br/>
  <a>
    Hi there <xsl:value-of select="FirstName" /> <xsl:value-of select="LastName" />!
  </a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <xsl:for-each select="Items/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="Key?" />
    <span> : </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="Value?" />
    <br/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</html>
```

As you can expect, the above for-each won't work...

The resulting XML is as follows:

```
<HelloWorldDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CommunicationTests.XsltEmail" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<FirstName>Foo</FirstName>
<Items xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <a:Key>Key1</a:Key>
        <a:Value>12345678912</a:Value>
    </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <a:Key>Key2</a:Key>
        <a:Value>ABC1234</a:Value>
    </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <a:Key>Key3</a:Key>
        <a:Value>Test</a:Value>
    </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
</Items>
<LastName>Bar</LastName>
```

What is the correct XSLT syntax for me to grab each key value pair from the Items dictionary?

Comment: And how exactly do you apply that xslt to your class?

Comment: What does your actual XML look like? I assume you're serializing the class before applying the stylesheet. Please add the XML to the question.

Comment: Sorry guys, I just added it.

Comment: If you add the actual XML that is in `xmlSerializedObject` to the question so we can see it without having to run your code, that will help.

Comment: Can you show the actual XML? Also: what are you using to serialize it? it isn't `XmlSerializer`, because "System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'HelloWorldDictionary'. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member HelloWorldDictionary.Items of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], because it implements IDictionary."

Comment: This might just be pure conjecture, but I have a sneaky suspicion that the real problem here is that the xml serialization step is failing as per my comment above, and you're not noticing the exception....

Comment: @MarcGravell you are right. I didn't realise that XmlSerializer wouldn't work for dictionaries so quickly changed the code to use  DataContractSerializer. I added the resulting XML to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the xml in the question, namespaces are the awkward bit; you'd need to  observe the namespaces throughout. Let's assume that you have:

```
xmlns:dc="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CommunicationTests.XsltEmail"
xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
```

at the top of your xslt; then we have (untested) something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/dc:HelloWorldDictionary">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <br/>
  <a>
    Hi there <xsl:value-of select="dc:FirstName" /> <xsl:value-of select="dc:LastName" />!
  </a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <xsl:for-each select="dc:Items/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="a:Key" />
    <span> : </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="a:Value" />
    <br/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</html>
```

However, IMO you'd be better off sticking to the default (empty) namespace in most cases; sadly, `DataContractSerializer` disagrees...

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just had to define the namespaces, make use of the aliases and everything worked, thank you!